# React/Redux - how to triggle customer event by action

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new to react world. I am using React/Redux/Sage to build up my web site. And I met a issue of how to trigger an event by action.

It looks like all the components in my page can fire an action like:

```
export const openExternalLinkAction = (url: string): ExternalLinkAction => ({
    type: OPEN_EXTERNAL_LINK,
    link: url
});
```

And I will have a handle to do the `windows.open(url)`, maybe there will be some other handler later, which more then open a url. I will have other custom events.

I have no idea of where and how to handle this action in react, any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is call "actions" in redux. You better learn the basics of redux
https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start from here.

redux have few concepts call, reducers, actions etc.

try implementing simple counter first, this video will be usefull

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJeXr1K3nyg
```